# Eliminar guiones de una lista y coger todo el rango

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista

tengo una lista de números, y me gustaría poder eliminar los guiones que puedan aparecer, por ejemplo si tengo 10-15, en mi lista debería aparecer 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15.

La lista en esta:

```
  numeros = ["2-3", "8", "10", "12", "15-19", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "51", "69", "96", "97", "200", "201", "202", "203", "222", "307", "341", "446", "500", "554", "580", "730", "760", "891", "892", "934", "952", "953", "954", "1031", "1032", "1418", "1475", "1478", "1530", "2000", "2300", "2301", "2784"]
```

El resultado final que espero es:

```
numeros_final = ["2"," 3", "8", "10", "12", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "51", "69", "96", "97", "200", "201", "202", "203", "222", "307", "341", "446", "500", "554", "580", "730", "760", "891", "892", "934", "952", "953", "954", "1031", "1032", "1418", "1475", "1478", "1530", "2000", "2300", "2301", "2784"]
```

Tengo dos guiones en la lista, 2-3 y 15-19, y son los que quiero eliminar pero guardar todo el rango de números.
Encontré esta consulta pero me dice que no puedo usar Split en una lista. Importante también usar Python 2.7, ya que encontré alguna solución en Python 3 pero es un requisito esa versión.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405208/how-to-convert-numeric-string-ranges-to-a-list-in-python

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Una forma relativamente sencilla sería:

- Suponer que cada elemento de esa lista es un rango separado por "-", y obtener los números de inicio y fin con `rango = dato.split("-")`.

  - Si realmente había un "-", esto nos dará en `rango` una lista de dos elementos, siendo `rango[0]` el primero (el `inicio` del rango) y `rango[-1]` el último (el `fin` del rango).
  - Si no había un "-" no pasa nada, pues en ese caso el resultado del split será una lista igualmente, pero con un solo elemento: el número en cuestión. Aún así, podemos seguir accediendo a `rango[0]` que nos da el primer (y único) elemento de esa lista y también a `rango[-1]` que nos da el último (y único) elemento de esa lista. En este caso, ambos (`inicio` y `fin`) serían el mismo número.
- Sea como sea, podemos construir `range(inicio, fin+1)` que nos dará otra lista con los números entre el inicio y el fin. Si ambos eran el mismo no pasa nada, funcionará igualmente y la lista resultante tendrá un solo número
- Usaremos `.extend()` para agregar los números conseguidos de este modo a una lista con el resultado.

Es decir:

```py
resultado = []

for dato in numeros:
  rango = dato.split("-")
  inicio = int(rango[0])
  fin = int(rango[-1])
  nuevos = range(inicio, fin+1)
  resultado.extend(nuevos)

print(resultado)
```

Puedes comprobar que funciona correctamente. En tu caso, los primeros elementos en la lista `resultado` serían:

```
[2, 3, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, ...
```

Esto funciona tanto en Python2 como en Python3. Las respuestas que enlazabas en tu pregunta probablemente funcionen también en Python2, no lo he verificado, pero el problema no era ese, sino que lo que tú tienes es una lista de cadenas, y no una sola cadena como en esa pregunta.

### Edición

Me he fijado en que tu pregunta pone como ejemplo deseado de salida una lista de cadenas. Mi código genera una lista de enteros. Si necesitas que sea de cadenas puedes hacer un `map(str, nuevos)` a la hora de añadirlos, esto ejecutará la función `str` (que convierte en cadena) a cada elemento de la lista `nuevos`.

```py
resultado = []

for dato in numeros:
  rango = dato.split("-")
  inicio = int(rango[0])
  fin = int(rango[-1])
  nuevos = range(inicio, fin+1)
  resultado.extend(map(str, nuevos))
```

y el resultado ahora sería

```
['2', '3', '8', '10', '12', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '21', '22', '23', '24', ...
```

Comment: Ostras, pues era mucha mas sencillo de lo que parecía... Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada! Si te ha servido puedes marcarla como aceptada